# How to link multiple providers on firebase with javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

I got the authentication for Email/Password and social login with Facebook/Google done, what i need is if the user sign's up with Facebook/Google to link that account on firebase if he previously signed up with Facebook/Google or Email.

I'm currently checking with the `'auth/email-already-in-use'` code.

I have done the separated part, but somehow i can't do the linking part. With the code provide nothings go linked on Firebase.

I'm Using Vuejs for Frontend, but this is basically all JavaScript for handling these kind of authentication. Let me know if you need some more description.

And i get when i click the signup button for Email/Password: `TypeError: self.googleSignin(...) is undefined`

Here is my code:

```
<template>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="display-block">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <input id="email" type="email" v-model="email" class="validate email-input-field" placeholder="Email Address">
                    <i class="material-icons prefix">email</i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <input type="password" v-model="password" class="validate password-input-field password-sign-up" placeholder="Password">
                    <i class="material-icons prefix">lock</i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col s12 padding-right-0">
                    <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light btn-sign-up" v-on:click="signUp" @keyup.enter>Sign Up
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col s12">
                    <a href="#modal-forgot-passoword" class="modal-trigger">Forgot password ?</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p class="light special-text-sign-up">or continue with</p>
            <div class="social-container">
                <a href="#" class="facebook" v-on:click="facebookSignin"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>Facebook</a>
                <a href="#" class="googleplus color-googleplus" v-on:click="googleSignin"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>Google</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end display block -->
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import firebase from 'firebase'
import axios from 'axios'


var googleProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
var facebookProvider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
export default {
    name: 'signUp',
    data: function() {
        return {
            email: '',
            password: '',
            credential: {}
        }
    },
    methods: {
        signUp: function(provider) {
            var self = this;
            firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password).then(
                (user) => {

                    self.registerProfile()
                    user.sendEmailVerification()
                    Materialize.toast('Email verification sent to: ' + this.email, 5000)
                },
                (err) => {
                    console.log("Error Code: " + err.code)
                    if (err.code == 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
                        var credential = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(self.email, self.password)
                        self.credential = credential
                            //check if google-link with facebook or if facebook link with google
                        self.googleSignin().then(function() {
                            firebase.auth().currentUser.link(self.credential).then(function(user) {
                                console.log("Account Linking success: " + user)
                            }, function(error) {
                                console.log("Error on linking accounts" + error)
                            })
                        })
                    } else {
                        Materialize.toast('Uppss: ' + err.message, 5000)
                        user.sendEmailVerification()
                    }

                }
            );
        },
        googleSignin: function() {
            var self = this
            firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(googleProvider).then(function(result) {
                var token = result.credential.accessToken;
                var user = result.user;
            }).catch(function(error) {
                var errorCode = error.code;
                var errorMessage = error.message;
                console.log(error.code)
                console.log(error.message)
            });
        },
        facebookSignin: function() {
            firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(facebookProvider).then(function(result) {
                var token = result.credential.accessToken;
                var user = result.user;
            }).catch(function(error) {
                var errorCode = error.code;
                var errorMessage = error.message;
                console.log("error code:" + error.code)
                console.log("error msg:" + error.message)
            });
        },
    },

}
</script>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? If you debug the code with some breakpoints, where does it stop?

Comment: I don't get any errors, as you can see i did not link any Facebook/Google linking, on the sign-up method i tried with Google but the linking part is not done on Firebase - so it does not work (I really don't know why :( )

Comment: I forgot to mention that i get a warning on console: TypeError: self.googleSignin(...) is undefined

Comment: It's because when you call `self` in that location, you are within a different closure so `self` doesn't refer to the same parent object.

Comment: i tried with `this` i got also undefined

Comment: Please see answer below

Answer (score 0):

I would try and get rid of your `self` references if possible. Here's a somewhat refactored approach:

```
var googleProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
var facebookProvider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();

var app = {}

app.data = function() {
    return {
        email: '',
        password: '',
        credential: {}
    };
};

app.signup = function(provider) {
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(app.data.email, app.data.password).then(
        (user) => {
            self.registerProfile()
            user.sendEmailVerification()
            Materialize.toast('Email verification sent to: ' + app.data.email, 5000)
        },
        (err) => {
            console.log("Error Code: " + err.code)
            if (err.code == 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
                var credential = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(app.data.email, app.data.password)
                app.data.credential = credential
                //check if google-link with facebook or if facebook link with google
                app.googleSignin().then(function() {
                    firebase.auth().currentUser.link(app.data.credential).then(function(user) {
                        console.log("Account Linking success: " + user)
                    }, function(error) {
                        console.log("Error on linking accounts" + error)
                    })
                })
            } else {
                Materialize.toast('Uppss: ' + err.message, 5000)
                user.sendEmailVerification()
            }
        }
    );
};

app.googleSignin = function() {
    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(googleProvider).then(function(result) {
        var token = result.credential.accessToken;
        var user = result.user;
    }).catch(function(error) {
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        console.log(error.code)
        console.log(error.message)
    });
};

app.facebookSignin = function() {
    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(facebookProvider).then(function(result) {
        var token = result.credential.accessToken;
        var user = result.user;
    }).catch(function(error) {
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        console.log("error code:" + error.code)
        console.log("error msg:" + error.message)
    });
};

export default {
    name: 'signUp',
    data: app.data,
    methods: {
        signUp: app.signup,
        googleSignin: app.googleSignin,
        facebookSignin: app.facebookSignin,
    }
}
```

Things I still notice:

- You have a call to `self.registerProfile()` however I can't see this function anywhere in your code?
- You reference `data` directly in your `signup` method however it would be better if this were passed in as a function parameter - is this possible?